# dask DataFrame query then sample error

Tags: python, parquet, dask

I was trying to concat `DaskDataFrame` from `read_parquet`, then apply query filter, then sample it to cap the final dataframe size to less than or equal to 10000. Here's the pseudo code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.concat([ dd.read_parquet(path, index='date').query("(col0 < 4) & (date < '20170201')")  
                 for path in files ], 
               interleave_partitions=True)
df = df.sample(float(10000) / max(10000, len(df)))
df = df.compute()
```

However, it failed with:

```
ValueError: a must be greater than 0

Traceback
---------
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 266, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)  
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/async.py", line 247, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)  
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/methods.py", line 143, in sample
    return df.sample(random_state=rs, frac=frac, replace=replace)  
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2644, in sample
    locs = rs.choice(axis_length, size=n, replace=replace, p=weights)  
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1391, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:16430)
```

If I don't do the `.query(...)` part, then it works fine. If I apply the query after the sample, it's also OK, but then I cannot control the final `DataFrame` size. Is there anything wrong with what I try to do here?

I'm running OS X 10.10.5, fastparquet 0.0.5, dask 0.14.1, python 2.7.12.

Comment: Does your `.query` return an empty dataframe? You can get a similar error from pandas with `pd.DataFrame().sample()`, so I would check `len(df)` after doing the query.

Comment: the data is fine, len(df) is in millions.

Comment: TomAugspurger's comment is right, though the length check should not be after the daskdataframe query, but rather inside dask.dataframe.sample(...) function (see the answer below), because it's more often that some of the partitions are empty, but the whole dask.dataframe is not empty.

Answer (score 4):

The "ValueError: a must be greater than 0" error is thrown because some of the pandas `DataFrame` are empty. This ValueError is thrown by `pandas.DataFrame.sample` method. Because we do sample after the dask query, and not all of the subtask of query will produce a non-empty `pandas.DataFrame`, this ValueError is almost guaranteed to happen.

The proper fix should be in `dask.dataframe` code: return `df` itself if it's empty, otherwise call `df.sample`:

```
> /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/methods.py(166)sample()
164 def sample(df, state, frac, replace):
165     rs = np.random.RandomState(state)
--> 166     return df.sample(random_state=rs, frac=frac, replace=replace)

i.e. return df.sample(random_state=rs, frac=frac, replace=replace) \
            if len(df) > 0 else df
```

Comment: I have been facing the same problem could You please help me to solve the problem. Links: 
``https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72156287/sample-size-valueerror-a-must-be-greater-than-0-unless-no-samples-are-taken?noredirect=1#comment127491266_72156287``
@user1527390
@mocica